# What is a simple definition for a CPU intensive application to answer in an interview?

Tags: node.js

I got asked during an online interview:- What is CPU Intensive Application? Answer it in 3-4 lines (briefly). I just want the simple definition that can be explained with few-real world examples.

Comment: Basically any program that doesn't block on I/O, network, or user input and just keeps executing instructions until it exits or is done with the input.  Video game is a great example.

Comment: @selbie I think you mean "any program that _blocks_ I/O..."

Comment: @smac89   No.  "Block on I/O" means the thread is halted until data is ready to be read or written on that I/O port (user input, file handle, network socket, etc...).  If the program isn't blocking on I/O, it's executing instructions.  Hence, using CPU.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't get any simpler than this forever loop:

```js
while (true) {}
```

To explain this, just remember that nodejs is single-threaded, so anything that blocks the [event-loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#what-is-the-event-loop) is bound to turn the process into a CPU-hungry beast. Of course the kernel is free to schedule the nodejs process as it sees fit, but the truth of the matter is that only that loop will get a chance to do anything meaningful in your program.

See also [Don't Block the Event Loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/)

Comment: The modern version of this answer is to do that loop in a different thread for each core. :)

Comment: @selbie since this is node, I didn't bother with attempting multiple thread because everything is single threaded. If OP is feeling adventurous, he can go ahead and run this in multiple node processes

Comment: fair enough.  It seems like such an open ended question regardless of programming lang.